# jQuery click() function to create circular carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel, jquery-click-event

The following code triggers an image gallery.

```
$('#coursepanel .thumbstrip img:first').click();
```

I want a timeout of 5000ms and then the next element to be triggered and then after another 5000ms the next to be triggered, etc... etc... Then if the element is the last in the set to trigger the first again.

Comment: Take a break, have a KitKat. Brain hurt is no good to programmers!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend checking out the jQuery Cycle plugin for this type of functionality. It will give you the functionality your looking for without the headache of programming it yourself.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

The parameters that control the speed of the effects are 'timeout' and 'speed'.  You can checkout all of the options on the options page: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html.

Comment: Not applicable as the gallery is not a JQuery gallery it is powered by CSS3. JQuery us used only to trigger class changing events

Comment: @Robin:  Please explain the exact difference between a "jQuery gallery" and one that only uses jQuery to "trigger class changing events".  Perhaps update your question with more explanation about why a plugin won't work and why the wheel needs re-invention.

Comment: Because all that is required here is an infinite loop triggering the events. The rest has already been done.

Comment: @Robin:  We're only trying to help, but that help is limited by the amount of effort you put into asking the question.  What you want is unclear and there's not enough information to even put together a JSFiddle without writing the whole thing for you from scratch.  Then again, these functions already exist as pointed out here by Joe.

Comment: Fare point. My apologies. In any case I have answered this question for now.

Answer (score 0):

Slight confusion chaps. We were not after a JQuery gallery, nor a plugin. Just an infinite loop that would shift through the elements. Brain seams to be fixed now.

```
function gslide(slide) {

    $(slide).click();
    setTimeout(function(){

        if($(slide).attr('id') == $('#coursepanel .thumbstrip img:last').attr('id'))
        {
            gslide($('#coursepanel .thumbstrip img:first'));
        }
        else {
        gslide($(slide).next());
        }
    },3000);
}


gslide($('#coursepanel .thumbstrip img:first'));
```